# SublimeLinter: PHP linting not working

Tags: php, sublimetext2

PHP linting is not working in [SublimeLinter](https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter) though it says `PHP: loaded` in the console. I'm working on Windows. Additionally, there are no options if I open the Command Palette except for `Extract Annotations`. Did anyone have the same problem and knows the solution?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Additionally, make sure you've given the path to php.exe in your user settings
    -

- (prefs>pkg settings>sublimelinter>settings - user)
- should look like this (if your path is "C:\xampp\php\php.exe"):

{
    "sublimelinter": true,
    "sublimelinter_executable_map":
    { "php":"/xampp/php/php.exe" }
}

Comment: I had to restart Sublime Text after I changed my user settings to get it working.

Answer (score 9):

on MAC OS X in sublimeText 2 once you have installed sublimelint package

`cmd+shift+p` to open command palette then enter or select `Preferences:SublimeLint - User`

This will open the setting file

Paste this exactly:

```
{
    "sublimelinter": true,
    "sublimelinter_executable_map":
 {
     "php":"/usr/bin/php"
 }
}
```

Save the file and restart sublime text 2. if you have an error such as it could not read the file, it's because you made a typo mistake. The setting file it must be a correctly formatted json.

if you have any problems do a `which php` in your terminal to be sure php is installed at `/usr/bin/php` and replace the path by what the `which` command gives you if it's different.

Answer (score 8):

I just had the same issue. The cause for my problem was that all PHP files where opened with the HTML5 syntax. You can check the current syntax by pasting the following command in your SublimeText console:

```
sublime.active_window().active_view().settings().get('syntax')
```

To set php as a default for the current file type, you can go to: view > syntax > Open all current extensions as... > php

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 4):

I had to use this in my user settings:

```
{
    "sublimelinter": true,
    "sublimelinter_executable_map":
    { "php": "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\PHP\\v5.3\\php.exe"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

i sovle this problem by change setting (where are bold) ,then restart sublime and try this php code to see sublime linter error

```
<?php echo "hello linter"  ?>
```

//not put semicolon
you see red dot on next line of php code

just change setting like below

```
"linters": {
        "php": {
            "@disable": false,
            "args": [],
            "excludes": []
        },
        "phpcs": {
            "@disable": true,
            "args": [],
            "excludes": [],
            "standard": "PSR2"
        }
    },
    "mark_style": "solid underline",
    "no_column_highlights_line": false,
    "passive_warnings": true,
    "paths": {
        "linux": [],
        "osx": [],
        "windows": [
            "put your php path or path of php.exe D:/wamp/bin/php/php5.4.3/"
        ]
    },
```

this two must change

```
"php": {
            "@disable": false,


        "phpcs": {
            "@disable": true,
```

Answer (score 1):

For my Windows i had to go with this:
php.exe file path on Windows 7 didn't do the trick for me, while
php-win.exe did:

```
{
    "sublimelinter_executable_map":
    {
        "php":"C:/php/php-win.exe"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes setting the php at the `sublimlinter_executable_map` does not work (for me). For me it just worked to add the path to the `php.exe` to the Windows System Environment Path Variable.

Answer (score 0):

For windows I did this and it worked, use \\ and it should work!

```
{

  "sublimelinter_executable_map":
    {

        "php":"C:\\Users\\Wasil\\Documents\\BitNami\\php\\php-win.exe"
    }

}
```