# Configuring the SublimeLinter Plugin to use PHP

Tags: php, sublimetext2

I installed the [SublimeLinter plugin](https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter) for Sumblime-text-2 in Ubuntu 12.04.

The PHP linting does not work. After an exhaustive search on the internet, I found out that I have to give the path to PHP in the sublimeLinter settings as below:

```
"sublimelinter_executable_map":
 {
     "php":"/usr/share/php"
 },
```

This was the path in the line **include_path** I found in the **phpInfo()**. But it does not work.
I tried escaping the special characters, and other paths like /usr/share/php5, /usr/lib/php5, but nothing seems to work.

Can anyone help with the correct configuration, so that I can get the linter functionality to work?

Note: There has been a previous unanswered question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11817164/sublimelinter-php-linting-not-working). I thought maybe I should ask it again, in a little more detail.

**UPDATE**: The [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11817164/sublimelinter-php-linting-not-working) has been answered and **solves this question** as well.

Answer (score 20):

1- Install node.js. Which, by the way, is pretty darn awesome in its own right.
2- Open up Sublime Text, and close all open files.
3- Head to Preferences->Package Settings->SublimeLinter->Settings – User (it will be empty if you haven’t messed with it before), and insert the following:

```
{

  "sublimelinter_executable_map":
    {
        "javascript":"C:/Program Files/nodejs/node.exe",
        "css":"C:/Program Files/nodejs/node.exe",
        "php":"C:/wamp/bin/php/php5.4.3/php.exe"
    }

}
```

This is also where you’d put paths to, say, php for linting. Make sure you get the path to node correct – this is the default location on a Windows 7 install. Save the file, close the file, and restart Sublime Text.

sources: http://fuzzytolerance.info/blog/2012/05/14/2012-05-15-getting-sublimelinter-running-on-windows/

Comment: My question was for Ubuntu 12.04 and not Windows!

Comment: Use ubuntu paths for php and node.js

Comment: @rgamber if this helped you appreciate developers by choosing the answers as correct.

Comment: Sorry the answer did not help. I already had the all the settings as mentioned in the link you gave. As my question mentions, I already had the path to the PHP file in the user-settings for the linter. The CSS and the Javascript paramteres add linting capabilites for the respective languages. Meanwhile someone had answered the original question in the link in my question. That just solved my problem, without having to install node.js (For the php-linting part). I already have upvoted that answer. Thanks for your help :).

Comment: You forgot to mention that you need to enable sublime linter by using "sublimelinter": true, before your  "sublimelinter_executable_map":

Answer (score 4):

For ubuntu system type in terminal:

```
which php
```

and use the result in your php path  (Preferences->Package Settings->SublimeLinter->Settings -User).

In my case it's:

```
{
    "sublimelinter_executable_map": {
       "php": "/usr/bin/php"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

php.exe file path on Windows 7 didn't do the trick for me, while
php-win.exe did:

```
{
    "sublimelinter_executable_map":
    {
        "php":"C:/php/php-win.exe"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

php-win.exe file path on Windows 7 didn't do the trick for me!!!

```
"sublimelinter_executable_map":
{
    "javascript":"C:/Program Files/nodejs/node.exe",
    "php":"C:/xampp/php/php-win.exe",
    "css":"C:/Program Files/nodejs/node.exe"
}
```